# Selenium - Loop over values for specific find_elements and click

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a very simple yet tricky question.

I am working with selenium.
I want the following line in the loop to click all elements, one by one,, where each element is specified by the "data-tooltip" attribute being equal to each value of `a`.

```
for i in a:
        tx_click = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@data-tooltip, i) and contains(@href, "/transaction/")]').click()
        driver.back()
```

where `a` is:

```
['5e8d1',
 '60e6f',
 '3ac8d',
 '598f5',
 'fab93']
```

What I get is that it always finds only the 1st element (i.e., "5e8d1") and loops over it.

It only works if I specify inside the `find_element` the exact string.

I appreciate any help!

**SOLUTION**: Use an f-string (edited suggestion from accepted comment).

```
tx_click = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//a[contains(@data-tooltip, "{i}") and contains(@href, "/transaction/")]').click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing the hardcoded `i` value in the XPath, not from the variable.

Updated your code to this for formatting variable into the XPath:

```
for i in a:
        tx_click = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//a[contains(@data-tooltip, {i}) and contains(@href, "/transaction/")]').click()
        driver.back()
```

This should work.

Comment: I had used an f-string in another try that didn't work. This is indeed the way, but not quite. Using {i} transforms the string in i into part of the general string. 
The solution is to use quotation too, so: "{i}".

Thanks for the help! I will update my question to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get all of elements that has the same identifier in a list by **find_elements**

after that you can put the elements that you got in for to click them one by one.

Comment: This is basically what the list a is. The source of the values does not really matter, since even if they are found or written manually, they are still a list of strings. Thanks for your time though!